# Why this async open url function slower than sequential one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why following async url open function slower than sequential one?
async_func is slower than sequential_exec in every case.
Why following async function taking too long time?

Python3.7 on Ubuntu 18.10 on virtualbox (Host: Windows10)

```
import urllib.request
import asyncio
import time

urls = [
        "https://www.google.co.jp",
        "https://github.com",
        "https://example.org",
        "https://www.python.org",
        "https://example.com",
        "https://stackoverflow.com",
        "https://ja.stackoverflow.com",
        "https://httpbin.org"
]


async def url_access(url):
    res = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    charset = res.info().get_content_charset()
    if charset is None:
        charset = "utf-8"
    body = res.read()
    print(body)

async def fetch():
    return await asyncio.wait([url_access(i) for i in urls])

def sequential_exec():
    for url in urls:
        res = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        charset = res.info().get_content_charset()
        if charset is None:
            charset = "utf-8"
        body = res.read()
        print(body)

def async_func(): #async function
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(fetch())
    loop.close()

seq_start = time.time()
sequential_exec()
seq_end = time.time()


async_func_start = time.time()
async_func()
async_func_end = time.time()
print("seq_time:", seq_end - seq_start)
print("async_func_time:", async_func_end - async_func_start)
```

Comment: [AIOHTTP](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) will be faster than urllib. I hadn't had a look, but would assume urllib isn't much optimized for async usage.

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous is achieved by `async stack`. The tasks to be performed are pushed on the stack and then are popped and run.
So if a function is async, it will be first put into `async stack`, no matter what and then is popped from there and executed.
Whereas the sequential function execute immediately.

So the time delay for push/pop operations adds to the execution time of async function.

Comment: Are there any ways to improve stack operation delay?

Comment: I don't think so. also since you accessing the internet also, so your internet speed can also be a factor